# sawtooth rest api installation error in python

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

What I have tried so far, Installed following ubuntu packages.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
sudo apt install build-essential automake pkg-config libtool libffi-dev
  libgmp-dev
sudo apt install libsecp256k1-dev
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 8AA7AF1F1091A5FD
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/1.0/stable xenial universe'
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install sawtooth python3-sawtooth-sdk
sudo apt-get install python3-sawtooth-rest-api
```

Then in the virtualenv, i have installed 
    pipenv install sawtooth-sdk 
    pipenv install sawtooth_rest_api
    Collecting sawtooth_rest_api

```
Error:  An error occurred while installing sawtooth_rest_api!
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sawtooth_rest_api (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for sawtooth_rest_api
```

Note:
I am trying to use sawtooth-marketplace, In this respoitory they have connected to the validator directly rather then submitting batch to rest api.

```
 from sawtooth_rest_api.messaging import Connection
 app.config.VAL_CONN = Connection(app.config.VALIDATOR_URL)
```

after installing python3-sawtooth-sdk as python package, couldn't import sawtoth-rest-api in python to get sawtooth-marketplace working.

Comment: There is no sawtooth_rest_api... when you install sawtooth components (e.g. via Docker compose or native) it will install the REST API processor. What are you trying to do maybe there is another aspect to help you out.

Comment: I am trying to use https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-marketplace,
there is an import statement in rest_api/main.py
from sawtooth_rest_api.messaging import Connection
I dont know how will i achieve this?

Comment: That package fetched in the Docker file (which assumes you are running this in docker) from after setting the deb repo: ` 'deb http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/1.0/stable xenial universe' >> /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I installed python3-sawtooth-rest-api separately on ubuntu, but still its showing error in python modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST API is in package `python3-sawtooth-rest-api`

I would install Sawtooth first:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 8AA7AF1F1091A5FD
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/1.0/stable xenial universe'
sudo apt update
aptitude install sawtooth python3-sawtooth-*
```

For detailed installation information see

- https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/sysadmin_guide/installation.html
- https://github.com/danintel/sawtooth-faq/blob/master/installation.rst#how-do-i-list-and-install-sawtooth-packages